# Vectorised way to count new events

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column to a data frame that will sequentially count the number of "events" where my "state" variable trasitions according to the following rules

```
0 to 1
1 to -1
-1 to 1
```

but not from either

```
1 to 0 or
-1 to 0
```

The example dataframe would deliver an output like the following

```
example <- data.frame(state = c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5), rep(-1, 5), rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5)), 
                      event.count = c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5)))   

state event.count
1      0           0
2      0           0
3      0           0
4      0           0
5      0           0
6      1           1
7      1           1
8      1           1
9      1           1
10     1           1
11    -1           2
12    -1           2
13    -1           2
14    -1           2
15    -1           2
16     0           2
17     0           2
18     0           2
19     0           2
20     0           2
21     1           3
22     1           3
23     1           3
24     1           3
25     1           3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can lag the vector to compare it to the previous value and provide the booleans to  `cumsum()`. In this case I used `data.table::shift()` which lags by `1L` as default, but you could also `dplyr`, `zoo`, or another package with a lag function.

```
library(data.table)

example$count2 = cumsum((shift(example$state, fill = 0) == 0 & example$state == 1)  |
                          (shift(example$state, fill = 1) == 1 & example$state == -1) |
                          (shift(example$state, fill = -1) == -1 & example$state == 1))
```

Or, if you wanted to make it a function. You could supply the vector and your changes (i.e., events) as arguments to an ellipses. If you go with the function, be sure to to add some checks (e.g., make sure all vectors in the ellipses are numeric and length 2, etc.):

```
event_counter = function(vec, ...) {
  args = list(...)
  
  l = lapply(args, function(x) data.table::shift(vec, fill = x[1]) == x[1] & vec == x[2])
  cumsum(do.call(pmax, l))
}

event_counter(example$state, c(0, 1), c(1, -1), c(-1, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this version.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a pain if your rules get much more complicated, but `case_when` works for a relatively simple set like the one above.

The 'counter' column records a 1 if the state changes according to the rules, and a zero otherwise.  The 'cumsum' column is just a cumulative sum of the 'counter' column.  Both included for illustration.

```r
example <- data.frame(state = c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5), rep(-1, 5), rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5)), 
                      event.count = c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5)))   

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

example %>% 
  mutate(
    counter = case_when(
      state == lag(state) ~ 0,
      state == 0 & lag(state) == 1 ~ 0,
      state == 0 & lag(state) == -1 ~ 0,
      is.na(lag(state)) ~ 0,
      TRUE ~ 1
                             )
    ) %>%
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(counter)) %>% 
  select(state,  counter, event.count, cumsum)
#>    state counter event.count cumsum
#> 1      0       0           0      0
#> 2      0       0           0      0
#> 3      0       0           0      0
#> 4      0       0           0      0
#> 5      0       0           0      0
#> 6      1       1           1      1
#> 7      1       0           1      1
#> 8      1       0           1      1
#> 9      1       0           1      1
#> 10     1       0           1      1
#> 11    -1       1           2      2
#> 12    -1       0           2      2
#> 13    -1       0           2      2
#> 14    -1       0           2      2
#> 15    -1       0           2      2
#> 16     0       0           2      2
#> 17     0       0           2      2
#> 18     0       0           2      2
#> 19     0       0           2      2
#> 20     0       0           2      2
#> 21     1       1           3      3
#> 22     1       0           3      3
#> 23     1       0           3      3
#> 24     1       0           3      3
#> 25     1       0           3      3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>